# Expression evaluation in C

Tags: c, operator-keyword, getchar

```
while ((x[num++] = getchar()) != ' ');
```

This reads a char at a time and stops if it encounters a space. 
But how does it evaluate the parenthesis with the space? What is the result of the parenthesis? So basically, what does this (`x[num++] = getchar()`) equal to, in order to compare it to a space?

I found this example in one of my class books, it was different and I got a warning so I guess it's a not good practice is it? How does the evaluation go here? Does it first assign the read value to `x[num]` and then compares it to space?

```
while(x[num++] = getchar() != ' ');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither version is good coding; both ignore the possibility of reaching EOF before reading a space, and both ignore the possibility of overflowing the buffer before reading a space.

The first is otherwise correct.  It contains an assignment:

```
x[num++] = getchar()
```

The result of an assignment is the value assigned.  So, if `getchar()` returns an 'X', the result of the assignment is 'X'.  Then the result of the assignment is compared with blank; they are different, and the loop repeats.  If `getchar()` returns a blank, then the result of the assignment is also a blank, and blank equals blank, so the loop terminates.

The second is plain faulty.  Because assignment has a lower precedence than `!=`, the result is as if the code read:

```
while (x[num++] = (getchar() != ' '))
    ;
```

That is, a character is read by `getchar()` and compared with blank, generating a value 1 if the character is not a blank and 0 if it is a blank.  This 0 or 1 is assigned to `x[num++]`, and then evaluated as a logical condition.  If the result was 0, the loop terminates; if the result was 1, the loop continues.  Note that the characters read are not recorded in this version - which is why the compiler gives the warning.  It is almost invariably a mistake; on those odd occasions when it is not a mistake, you can tell the compiler that by providing the extra parentheses to make your intention crystal clear to the compiler - and to your human audience, the other people who will read your code.  (Remember: if you come back in 6 months, or even 6 weeks, you'll be a different person and may well have difficulty remembering such subtleties.  Make it plain to everyone.  There is a fine balance to be drawn between over-parenthesizing and under-parenthesizing code.)

The code should probably read:

```
int c;
int max = sizeof(x) - 1;
int num = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && num < max && (x[num++] = c) != ' ')
    ;
```

Note, in particular, that `c` must be an `int` and not a `char`.

Comment: Does c have to be int because otherwise it can't store EOF?

Comment: @Cookie503: yes, that's correct.  `getchar()` returns an `int` because it must return every valid character value plus one different value, EOF.

Comment: @Leffler I am interested in more details about "every valid character value" in the context of a getchar(). When a char has 32 bits, we assume getchar() reads an octect that then is stored into a 32bit char, or rather we assume that getchar() can de facto read 4 octects to fill the 32-bits char, and so comparing with EOF alone would be wrong and feof is strictly needed to know if we are dealing with a "-1" read from the stream or an actual EOF?

Comment: @ShinTakezou: you are right that if `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)`, then clearly `int` cannot hold more values than `char`.  See [Rule FIO35-C](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FIO35-C.+Use+feof%28%29+and+ferror%28%29+to+detect+end-of-file+and+file+errors+when+sizeof%28int%29+%3D%3D+sizeof%28char%29) at the CERT Secure Coding Standard web site for a discussion of this.

Comment: @Leffler: On my compiler char holds values from -128 to 127. Since on my platform EOF is -1, is there any other reason why I should not use char to store values for getchar()? Here, I'm referring just to my situation.

Comment: @Cookie503: In C99, `getchar()` is defined in terms of `getc()`, and `getc()` is defined in terms of `fgetc()`, and `fgetc()` is defined as: '_If the end-of-file indicator for the input stream pointed to by stream is not set and a
next character is present, the `fgetc` function obtains that character as an `unsigned
char` converted to an `int` ..._' so `getchar()` always returns a value 0..255 (when CHAR_BIT == 8) or EOF, even if plain `char` is signed.  If you assign to a plain `char` before testing, then you can get confused; that is why it is crucial to assign to an `int`.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: note, too, the EOF is required to be negative, but all the Unicode characters in UTF-32 are positive values (U+0000 .. U+10FFFF), so it would be a very unusual 32-bit character encoding that ran into problems with EOF being confused with a valid character.

Comment: @Leffler but,I mean,let us suppose I have a UTF-8 text file containing "è"(2 octets);if I getchar() on a CHAR_BIT=8 system,I get the first octet.If I getchar() on a CHAR_BIT=9 system,I guess I still obtain just the first octet.If I getchar() on a CHAR_BIT=16 system,do I obtain both octets from the input stream?And if instead of "è" I have "ab",I get 'ab' into the char(and endianness scrambled?)?Then to get just an octet I must use fread?(fread's man I can read talk about bytes,which is ambiguous as "char";does they mean octets?)I hoped fgetc read octets even if C-char bits > 8.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: your original question/comment was about CHAR_BIT=32, which is less exciting than CHAR_BIT=16. You're right that if you managed to find a CHAR_BIT=9 system, `getchar()` would most likely return the first octet with no sign bit. UTF-8 would not be a natural encoding to use on a CHAR_BIT=16 system. If the system was aware that the data was UTF-8 on input, it would presumably read the 1-4 octects of UTF-8 data, and return them in one or two 16-bit units (presumably as the low and then high surrogates, or vice versa).  ...to be continued...

Comment: @ShinTakezou: (continuing) If the system is unaware that its input is UTF-8, then the application would have to decode it.  I think it would only work reliably if the input did not try interpreting the double-octets as UTF-16, but rather as some 16-bit codeset for which any bit pattern is valid; I may be being too pessimistic. But the application would have to know whether the I/O is little-endian or big-endian, and would have to split each double-octet into components to identify the UTF-8 boundaries properly, and convert them into UTF-16. Definitely tricky to think about, and to get right.

Comment: @Leffler it's a nightmare rather!The existence of fgetwc/getwchar and similar make me believe that fgetc/getchar are encoding-agnostic.As said I thought that getchar,though its unhappy name,would read just an octet,not as many octets fit the char type;and that there were no relationship between char(in getchar) and character as glyph(represented with 1 or more octet in some encoding),but only a"legacy"relationship with the name of the C type.But,if getchar would read as much octet it can stuff in a char type,it must be absolutely avoided for reading both text file and"binary"file>>>

Comment: <<<I imagine a parser for C itself that uses getchar,it is going to read "for";on"normal" system it would get'f' as expected;on weird systems it reads'fo',and a matching with'f'fails...How is it possible to write portable code if getchar behaves like this?Everyone should stick to fread;but alas my man talk about"byte"(not octet);should I doubt that on a system where C char type is 32bits(and bytes too),fread can't read an octet?I hope no.Though,manuals use ambiguous words"byte","char";are std ISO man less ambigouos?I've used fgetc to read binarydata,reading"legacy"c(har)as octet from a stream!

Comment: btw, thank you for answering, I think I should make my first question, but I don't know exactly how to write it yet... there are many related doubt and my persuasion that if things are like that or similar, all stream I/O in C is totally broken and 100% of the written C code work just since 99.999999% of the systems (where it has sense to do stream I/O) have CHAR_BIT=8 or < 16 (so that it can't hold two octets!)

Answer (score 3):

In C, `a = b` is an *expression*. It assigns `b` to `a`, and then returns `a`. Therefore, the condition in the while loop means:

1. Call `getchar()` to get the user's input
2. Assign the result of `getchar` to `x[num]`.
3. Increase `num` by 1
4. Check if `x[num]` is not equal to a space `' '`.

i.e.

```
while (true) {
  x[num] = getchar();
  num ++;
  if (!(x[num] != ' '))
    break;
}
```

The 2nd example has a totally different behavior. This is because the `!=` expression will be evaluated before the assignment `=` without the parenthesis. Therefore, the 2nd example means

1. Call `getchar()` to get the user's input
2. Check if `x[num]` is not equal to a space `' '`.
3. Assign the result in step 2 (`true` or `false`) to `x[num]`
4. Increase `num` by 1

The warning is because it's easy to mistakenly write `while (a = b)` to mean `while (a == b)`.

Comment: So it return b, thank you! Is it bad practice to not use the parenthesis as in the second example?

Comment: @Cookie: The 2nd example is simply wrong. It is not the same as the 1st example. See update.

Comment: @Cookie503 && has higher precedence than = , so omitting the parenthesis `x[num++] = getchar() != ' '` would mean the same as `x[num++] = (getchar() != ' ')`, that's not what you want. That would store 0 or 1 in `x[num]` depending on whether `getchar() != ' '` was false or true.